# Set a message box's icon from a combobox

Tags: c#, combobox

im trying to display a message box and wanted to customise the icon from a combobox. I added each Icon like "Error, Warning" as combobox items but im not sure how i would make that determine the icon.

```
MessageBox.Show(txtMessageBody.Text, txtMessageHeader.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.cbMessageboxIcon.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

i need something like that, if anyone could help me id be very appriciative

Answer (score 0):

If Its a Combo Box Icon then why you are converting it into the toString?? 
Make Your Own Custom Message Box and do what ever you want 
[Here is Project Source of Custom MessageBox and Modify according to your willing](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/17253/a-custom-message-box)

[image]

Comment: I wanted to use a combo box so its easy for the user to choose one instead of a popup

Comment: its also a self Made Combo box type . i also made for myself but its in WPF(xaml ). if you want some special purpose Messagebox Made it according to your own requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is a late answer, but you can use [**`Enum.Parse()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxydatf9(v=vs.110).aspx) to turn a string representation into an actual enumeration value/object:

```
MessageBoxIcon messageBoxIcon = Enum.Parse(typeof(MessageBoxIcon), cbMessageboxIcon.SelectedItem.ToString(), true);

MessageBox.Show(txtMessageBody.Text, txtMessageHeader.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, messageBoxIcon);
```